# Use OpenGL ES to create an iPhone painting tool?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Is it feasible to use OpenGL ES to create an iPhone raster graphics editor like SketchBook Mobile(http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=13872203)? Any related reference(tutorial, sample) you can recommend?

Why I try to use OpenGL ES? Because it's hardware accelerated and cross-platform.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Apple's own GLpaint sample app might be a good starting point.